# Expected Number of Occurrences of A Series of Events

Tags: probability, statistics

This question may be obvious and easy to find but I don't know what to search or what this kind of problem is called.

If there is a series of 10 random events each time with a 30% chance of occurring, what is the expected number of times of the event occurring (out of those ten). Or put slightly differently, if treating the 10 events as one event with 10 possible outcomes (of how many times the individual events occurred), which of those outcomes is most likely and how is the probability calculated.

I can do this simulated in code but I want a theoretical way of calculating it and other similar problems.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I think you talk about of events $A_1, A_2, A_3, \cdots , A_{10}$ with P(A_i)=0.3 then you have $2^{10}$ outcomes, not 10. But, maybe, I'm missing something.

Comment: If we use the example of a coin toss instead, each time a coin is tossed the chance is 50%. If tossing 10 coins and recording how many times heads is landed, and then repeating this, I would imagine the average number of times it lands heads out of ten across many sets of ten would be 5. But what about with events that aren't 50/50.

Comment: I think you are talking then about the number of successfull events in ten trials (eleven outcomes) then the probability of x successfull events in ten trials are ${10\choose x} p^x(1-p)^{10-x}$ where $p=0.3$

Comment: Let $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10, p=0.3). $ Then $\mu_X = E(X) = np.$ For example, if $n = 3, p=1/2,$ then $P(X=0) = 1/8, P(X=1) = 3/8, P(X=2) = 3/8), P(X=3) = 1/,$ from formula for binomial PDF (or PMF). Then, by def'n of $E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^3 kP(X=k) =0(1/8)+1(3/8)+2(3/8)+3(1/8) = 12/8 = 3/2 = np.$ Maybe you can find a more general proof in your text of online. // Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Expectation) under Expectation.